# Incrementing variable based on number of processes/cores

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, increment

I would like to increase the efficiency of this function by splitting the incrementation based on how many cores/processes are present.

```
def mine_block(self, core_number):
    """Mine block once node has a certain number of transactions."""
    difficulty_zeroes = self.difficulty * "0"  # Number of zeroes needed
    # Mine block until an appropriate nonce has been found
    while (self.hash[0:self.difficulty] != difficulty_zeroes):
        self.nonce += core_number
        self.hash = self.compute_block_hash()
    print ("Block mined.")
```

I have implemented a solution based loosely on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921576/keep-unified-count-during-multiprocessing). I had no errors but I noticed as I increased the number of cores/processes, it took longer to "mine" my respective blocks. Essentially, what I want to do is have each process increment the nonce by its respective ordering number. For example: if we had 4 processes, the first process would increment the nonce by 1, the 2nd process by 2, the 3rd process by 3, and so on until the condition is met. I assumed that multiprocessing would do this automatically, but it is not.

My current multiprocessing implementation looks like this:

```
def mine_blocks(self):
    """Use multiprocessing to enhance block mining."""
    nonce_processes = []
    core_range = range(1, self.numcores + 1)
    for core in core_range:
        p = mp.Process(target=self.mine_block, args=(core,))
        p.start()
        nonce_processes.append(p)
    for process in nonce_processes:  # Terminate processes
        process.terminate()
```

Comment: Why do you immediately terminate all your processes as soon as you're done starting all of them?

Comment: You've got other problems, but that one is particularly glaring.

Comment: I was following the syntax of the question I linked above, but I also used join instead of terminate and had similar problems.