# Python having problems getting existing global variable

Tags: python, flask

I have this code here

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from multiprocessing import Process
import cv2
app = Flask(__name__)
def gen_frames():
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_V4L2)
    while True:
        global frame
        success, frame = camera.read()
        if not success:
            break

def get_frames():
    global frame
    ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
    frame = buffer.tobytes()
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
            b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(get_frames(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Process(target=gen_frames)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    app.run(host= '0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

It's a script to get my camera, and then stream it onto a local site, since I found my original script (where gen_frames and get_frames were combined into one), didn't work with multiple viewing at the same time. Except now, with this script, it is now giving me the error:
`NameError: name 'frame' is not defined` in the 14th line. Please lmk if you find a solution. Thanks so much

UPDATE:

I have tried adding a new variable called frame after the app variable.
This solved the original problem of not being defined, but raised a new issue shown below.

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imencode'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
>  - Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'img'
```

Also, I'm using `frame = (np.random.rand(1000,1000,3)*255).astype(np.uint8)`

Still need help :|

Comment: On line 9, in gen_frames, I'm pretty sure it runs the script before the get_frames function

Comment: you need to have a `frame = something` outside the functions too

Comment: This is because you define it in a `Process` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29921576/keep-unified-count-during-multiprocessing

Comment: Yep, I tried, it gives another error, called `cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'imencode'`

Comment: globals aren't common/shared between processes - each has its own memory space.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do, broadcast from one camera to multiple end points that would get the same video output?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: A conceptually correct implementation would be to have a redis datastore that stores each frame and keeps it around until all clients read it then delete the frame. Practically you want to start from scratch and do websocket to transmit the data and create code that runs in the space where a usual web server like apache runs so as to control the interaction between the processes created by user requests. There should be libraries for that on the internet.